# Caesar Cipher not returning correct key

Tags: c, encryption, caesar-cipher

So my decrypter program seems to not be able to find the key and implement  it by itself. I noticed that if I changed the key to equal -5 which is the correct key it would print out the decrypted text correctly. However I am unable to figure out how to make the program figure it out by itself without having me to put it in manually. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

**rotUtils.h**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#include "rotUtils.h"

int rotate(int c, int n){
  if (n == 0) return c;
  int nRot = abs(n) % (RANGECHAR + 1);
  if(n > 0)
    return rotatePlus(c + nRot);
  else
    return rotateMinus(c - nRot);
}

int rotatePlus(int sum){
  int diff = sum - MAXCHAR;
  if (sum > MAXCHAR) sum = MINCHAR + diff - 1;
  return sum;
}

int rotateMinus(int sum){
  int diff = MINCHAR - sum;
  if (sum < MINCHAR) sum = MAXCHAR - diff + 1;
  return sum;
}
```

**decrypt.cpp**

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include "rotUtils.h"

bool solved( char decodearr[], char dictarr[][30], int size1, int size2){

    char* compared;
    bool result = false;

    for(int j = 0; j < size2; j++){

    compared = strstr( decodearr, dictarr[j]);

    }
    if( compared != '\0'){

     result = true;

         }
    return result;

}

int decode( char codearr[], char dictarr[][30], int size1, int size2)
    {
    bool solution = false;
    int key = -50; This is where I had to change it to -5 to solve 

    char decodearr[10000];
    while(solution == false && key < 51)
    {
     for( int i = 0; i < size1; i++)
        {
        if(!isspace(codearr[i]))
         {
          decodearr[i] = rotate(codearr[i], key);
          }
        else
          decodearr[i] = codearr[i];


    }

    solution = solved( decodearr, dictarr, size1, size2);
    if( solution == false)
     {
      key++;
      }
    }

  for( int j = 0; j < size1; j++)
    {
    codearr[j] = decodearr[j];
    }
  return key;
}

    int main( int argc, char* argv[])
    {
    char* file = argv[1];
    char* dictionary = argv[2];
    char code[10000];
    char dict[30000][30];
    FILE* codeFile;
    codeFile = fopen(file, "r");
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int key;
    FILE* dictFile;
    dictFile = fopen(dictionary, "r");

    while(!feof(codeFile))
    {
    code[i] = fgetc(codeFile);
    i++;
    }

    code[ i ]= '\0';
    fclose(codeFile);

    while(!feof(dictFile))
    {
    fscanf(dictFile, "%s", dict[j]);
    j++;
    }

    key = decode(code, dict, i, j);
    fclose(dictFile);

        for(int k = 0; k < i; k++)
        {
        printf("%c", code[k]);
        }

    printf( "\nThe key is: %d\n", key);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: At the moment, you just check one key, -50. You must probe various keys until a good percentage of the words in the decoded message are words in the dictionary. That means you need a dictonary lookup, probably a binary search. The brute force attack would just try all possible keys, of which there aren't many in a Caesar cipher. If you want, you could add some heuristics, for example by assuming that the most frequent code letter is an 'e', and try such keys first.

Comment: @MOehm I added the header file with the rotate function if that helps. And I do use a smallDictionary file in argv[2] that is read.

Comment: Yes, I've seen that. Do you have a function that tells you whether a word is in the dictionary? (I assume that the words in the dict are sorted and that you can use a binary search. Or is a "smallDictionary" already implemented?)

Comment: @MOehm The words in the dict are sorted but I don't have a function yet to tell if it is a word. Would i use strstr again to compare it to a word in the dictionary?

Comment: You could use `strstr`, but it will be slow. You should find the words (ie stretches of letters without punctuation) in the decoded text and then run a binary search on it. Binary search is a very basic algorithm; you should be able to find ressources online.

Comment: Ah, now I've seen that you already compare the decoded text and the dict. Look at gia's comment. But even if you fix this, your logic isn't correct: You don't have to check whether every word in dictionary is in the message; you have to check how many words in the message are in the dictionary.

Comment: yup, he's correct, that's why I asked you to print all solutions and not to stop with the first you get, so you see what happens. Later you can change "result=true" to a counter instead, after your dictionary check test the counter vs a value you like for a proper "result" (eg. 25 words out of 100), I would still prefer returning a set of possible results, than trying to choose _the one_, a list helps more when you are testing millions of possibilities. But that is up to you.

Comment: @gia How would I be able to print these solutions i get in the main function?

Comment: your program seems single threaded, you can print anything anywhere without fear :), if you want to store the results anyway, a quick way is to create a global array and store there, you can access it from any part of your code, if you prefer better practices, you can use the return value, return the array with all the possible keys instead of a single key. For millions of tests I suggest you write to a file you create instead (like a log file), or save to a database (more work).

Answer (score 0):

Solved() will only return true if there is a match on the last dictionary word currently, you have to move that check inside. You could print to screen whenever you find a key that has a match on your dictionary and/or keep a list of possible keys then print after you are done with them all, right now you would exit as soon as you find any match even if it was just luck.

Comment: What do you mean by having to move that check inside?

Comment: On solved(), if(compared...) move it inside the for() previous to it. Right now it is outside the for() so it only gets executed after you are done looping all your dictionary words.